# How does one correctly apply filters to an image array?

Tags: java, matrix, filter

My question does not refer to what operators I need to use to manipulate matrices, but rather what is actually being sought by doing this procedure.

I have, for example, an image in matrix form on which I need to perform several operations (this filter is one of them). After converting said image to grayscale, I need to apply the following filter

```
float[][] smoothKernel = {
            {0.1f,0.1f,0.1f},
            {0.1f,0.2f,0.1f},
            {0.1f,0.1f,0.1f}
    };
```

on it.

The assignment file gives this example [image: this example], so I assumed that when asked to "smooth" the image, I had to replace every individual pixel with an average of its neighbors (while also making sure special cases such as corners or side were handled properly).

The basic idea is this:

```
public static float[][] filter(float[][] gray, float[][] kernel) {
    // gray is the image matrix, and kernel is the array I specifed above
    float current = 0.0f;
    float around = 0.0f;
    float[][] smooth = new float[gray.length][gray[0].length];
    for (int col = 0; col < gray.length; col++) {
        for (int row = 0; row < gray[0].length; row++) { 
        //first two for loops are used to do this procedure on every single pixel
        //the next two call upon the respective pixels around the one in question 
            for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
                for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                    around = at(gray, i + col, j + row); //This calls a method which checks for the 
                                             //pixels around the one being modified
                    current += around * kernel[i+1][j+1]; 
                    //after the application of the filter these are then added to the new value
                }
            }
            smooth[col][row] = current; 
            current = 0.0f;
            //The new value is now set into the smooth matrix
        }
    }
    return smooth;
}
```

My dilemma lies in if I have to create this new array `float[][] smooth;` so as to avoid overriding the values of the original (the image outputted is all white in this case...). From the end product in the example I linked above I just cannot understand what is going on.

What is the correct way of applying the filter? Is this a universal method or does it vary for different filters?

Thank you for taking the time to clarify this.

EDIT: I have found the two errors which I detailed in the comments below, implemented back into the code, everything is working fine now.

I have also been able to verify that some of the values in the example are calculated incorrectly (thus contributing to my confusion), so I will be sure to point it out in my next class.

Comment: Creating a new array seems correct to me.  I'd do the same.  What problem are you having?

Comment: @markspace I get a white image, when it should output a grayscale image with some blur

Comment: @markspace I just realized that I have to set `current = 0.0f` after every `smooth[col][row]`, but the image is all gray now

Comment: @markspace ok i found it nevermind, there was an indices problem, I'll fix it in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question has been solved by ulterior methods, I am however not deleting it in hopes other people can benefit from it. The original code can be found in the edits.

A more advanced colleague of mine helped me to note that I was missing two things: one was the issue with resetting the current variable after computing the "smoothed" variables in the new array (resulting in a white image because this value would get increasingly larger thus surpassing the binary color limit, so it was set to the max). The second issue was that I was continuously iterating on the same pixel, which caused the whole image to have the same color (I was iterating the new array). So I added these specifications in, and all works fine since.